# php array looping issues

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I create and populate an array like this.

```
  var randomnumber=new Array(); 

    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
             randomnumber[i]=Math.random();

}
```

Then i put the array into a hidden input

```
    document.getElementById("field").value = randomnumber;
```

Then i call the file that processes that file. I get this error:  Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

```
$myArray=$_GET['field'];


for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<10;$j++)
    {
        echo $myArray[$i][$j];////error is on this line
    }

}
```

How else would I loop through a 2d array?

Comment: `var_dump($_GET['field'])` ?

Comment: Try to use `foreach` instead of having the fixed array length. Let's see if that will work.

Comment: What does `$_GET['field']` contain?

Comment: Without letting us know what does $_GET ['field'] contains ....no one can help you and aslo makes your question not constructive

Comment: i edited and reposted....

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
foreach($myArray as $i)
{
    foreach($i as $j)
    {
        echo $j;
    }
}
```